# jquery 1.6.2/jquery.min.js and foundation2/jquery.min.js

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I tried using some projects with jquery already  like:

http://awardwinningfjords.com/2009/06/16/iphone-style-checkboxes.html

and foundation framework
http://foundation.zurb.com/

the problem is: foundation framework has i think jquery min diferent

```
<script src="oundation2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and the example in top using:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

when i remove: `<script src="foundation2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

the effect work perfect, but i cannot remove because i need foundation  framework for my website.

some help how to resolve this conflict?

Comment: Include the foundation framework first, then don't include your own version of jQuery. Or, modify the foundation framework to not include jquery and include your own version of jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a glitch in SO, or your question wasn't formatted correctly, but this part doesn't give much away ;)

> and the example in top using:
>
> when i remove:

Regardless, @user964836 has given you the answer - simply organize the resource references.

However to be more verbose, using the current build of foundation (3.2.5 at time of writing) I have replicated your problem, and solved it by simply moving this line (just before closing body tag):

```
<script src="javascripts/foundation.min.js"></script>
```

Up to the head, before any reference to the iPhone checkbox resources.